# Family of curves not including a particular member

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider two lines l1: 3x-2y-12=0  l2: 2x+y+6=0, family of curves passing through points of intersections of these two lines with x and y axes is (3x-2y-12)(2x+y+6)+(lambda)xy=0 . This family clearly, always passes through 3 fixed (non-collinear) points (-3,0) (4,0) (0,-6). But the equation(of family) itself can never be a circle for any lambda. I can't figure out where I am going wrong.
Please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only looking at a pencil. Here's a [net of conics through three points](https://www.geogebra.org/m/drgpdhs9).

Comment: No I am just saying why this equation of family is incomplete?  It must contain all the conics passing through those points.

Comment: Your family is only one dimensional and five points, no three on a line, determine a conic so there's two degrees of freedom.

Comment: Yes but it is also true that a unique circle passes through 3 non collinear points

Comment: True. But this unique circle isn't captured by your pencil. The two-dimensional linear system, the net of conics, does capture this circle.